# ArgumentError: missing required :bucket option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have all of my environment variables set. I checked it with `heroku config` but still I am unable to save an image using paperclip gem and aws s3 in the development environment and receive the `ArgumentError: missing required :bucket option` error. I have even tried changing `AWS_BUCKET` to `S3_BUCKET_NAME`, but still without success. I have been through every stack overflow question I could find even remotely related to the subject but still cannot find a solution.

**Gems**

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk-v1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '> 2'
```

**Model**

```
  has_attached_file :banner_image,
                :storage => :s3,
                :url =>':s3_domain_url',
                :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
                styles:
                    {
                        large: '600x600>',
                        medium: '300x300>',
                        thumb: '100x100>'
                    },
                default_url: '/images/:style/missing.png',
                :s3_credentials => Proc.new{|a| a.instance.s3_credentials }

  def s3_credentials
    {:bucket => Rails.application.secrets.aws_bucket, :access_key_id => Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id, :secret_access_key => Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key}
  end

  validates_attachment_content_type :banner_image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

**development.rb**

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_protocol => 'https',
    :s3_region => Rails.application.secrets.aws_region,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => Rails.application.secrets.aws_bucket,
      :access_key_id => Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id,
      :secret_access_key => Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key
    }
  }
```

**secrets.rb**

```
development:
  admin_name: <%= ENV["ADMIN_NAME"] %>
  admin_email: <%= ENV["ADMIN_EMAIL"] %>
  admin_password: <%= ENV["ADMIN_PASSWORD"] %>
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"] %>
  domain_name: <%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>
  aws_access_key_id: <%= ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] %>
  aws_secret_access_key: <%= ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] %>
  aws_bucket: <%= ENV["AWS_BUCKET"] %>
  aws_region: <%= ENV["AWS_REGION"] %>
  secret_key_base: hchwhc987h23y4bf93h4f928374h9f78h329487hf98723h4f789h234987hf89723h4f897h23498fh723487hf823974hf9872h34f7823489f

test:
  domain_name: example.com
  secret_key_base: hd78h2399d0a6315b087b3bebd35uhfhf8u3h4fh348fh92837h4f987h234f897h23487fh23897h4f98732h4f987h23498f7h324987fh239748f8237h4f987h3947hf

development_heroku:
  admin_name: <%= ENV["ADMIN_NAME"] %>
  admin_email: <%= ENV["ADMIN_EMAIL"] %>
  admin_password: <%= ENV["ADMIN_PASSWORD"] %>
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"] %>
  domain_name: <%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>
  aws_access_key_id: <%= ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] %>
  aws_secret_access_key: <%= ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] %>
  aws_bucket: <%= ENV["AWS_BUCKET"] %>
  aws_region: <%= ENV["AWS_REGION"] %>
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>

staging:
  admin_name: <%= ENV["ADMIN_NAME"] %>
  admin_email: <%= ENV["ADMIN_EMAIL"] %>
  admin_password: <%= ENV["ADMIN_PASSWORD"] %>
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"] %>
  domain_name: <%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>
  aws_access_key_id: <%= ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] %>
  aws_secret_access_key: <%= ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] %>
  aws_bucket: <%= ENV["AWS_BUCKET"] %>
  aws_region: <%= ENV["AWS_REGION"] %>
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  admin_name: <%= ENV["ADMIN_NAME"] %>
  admin_email: <%= ENV["ADMIN_EMAIL"] %>
  admin_password: <%= ENV["ADMIN_PASSWORD"] %>
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"] %>
  domain_name: <%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>
  aws_access_key_id: <%= ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] %>
  aws_secret_access_key: <%= ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] %>
  aws_bucket: <%= ENV["AWS_BUCKET"] %>
  aws_region: <%= ENV["AWS_REGION"] %>
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Comment: Adding all those ENV keys to secrets.yml seems like a lot of duplication. It also introduces a source of errors  and indirection since you should not check secrets.yml into git. I would just use `ENV.fetch("SOME_KEY")` directly from your initializers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you ever think to add the environment variables to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="KJAHSDH9HD0SAD89H"
export AWS_BUCKET="staging_value"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="HASDF78H/JHIUDHSHHS8DH7USD7CH"
```

• then run `source .bash_profile`

• restart terminal

This solves the issue for me.